# preferences.getBoolean causing a crash

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've been staring at this code for a while now and I cant see where I am going wrong. I am trying to implement an overlay activity which runs on the applications first run only.

I am getting a nullpointer Exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My onCreate():

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    View topLevelLayout;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    topLevelLayout= findViewById(R.layout.activity_instructions);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if (isFirstTime()) {
        topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

And the isFirstTime method:

```
private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false); // The program crashes here
    if (!ranBefore) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
        topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        topLevelLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return ranBefore;
}
```

Comment: you need to look at `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` because it's returning null which is why you're getting an NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the preferences like this

```
 preferences =getSharedPreferences("yourpreferencename", 0);
```

your `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` returns null

Comment: It actually seems that topLevelLayout is null. 'topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);' is causing the crash now. I cannot see why though. Its being declared in the line above.

Comment: you're calling `findViewById` but you're passing in a layout

Comment: Ok, I dont fully understand why. what ID should I be passing?

Comment: @L337BEAN - the ID you gave the topLevelLayout item in your activity_main.xml.. If it's `android:id="@+id/top_item"` in the XML file in your code you would use `findViewById(R.id.top_item);`

Comment: @L337BEAN method name it self suggest that findViewById, it will find view by a uniqueid... When ever you setContentView(yourlayout), your layout will be inflatted and the already and the views can be identified by already generated ids in your R.java

Comment: @dymmeh, I didnt give it one in activity_main.xml. Its a seperate layout for a seperate activity. I believe the example I was working from did suit what I want to do. I understand now why this isint working. Thanks!

Comment: You can inflate the layout to get the desiredview